# Inserting Part Dividers Into Markdown ePub with Pandoc

Tags: markdown, pandoc, epub

I'm assembling a book with individual chapters constructed as markdown files with Pandoc. Currently, I'm successfully using a script like this to combine the metadata document with the chapters to create an ePub document:

```
pandoc -o book.epub metadata.yaml \  
        chapters_markdown/chapter_01.md \
        chapters_markdown/chapter_02.md \
        chapters_markdown/chapter_03.md \
        chapters_markdown/chapter_04.md
```

However, between several chapters, I would like to additionally like to group several chapters together into parts, similar to the way you would use the LaTeX commands:

```
\part{First part}
\chapter{First chapter}
\chapter{Second chapter}
\part{Second part}
\chapter{Third chapter}
\chapter{Fourth chapter}
```

Is there any way to do this with markdown and Pandoc?

Comment: pandoc behaves the same regardless how you split your input files. what matters is that you use the right headers, i.e. `# header1` and `## header2`...

Comment: @mb21, the LaTeX `part` header is higher order than a Markdown `# chapter` header. There is no direct Markdown equivalent that I'm aware of, so I'm wondering what the best way to do this is.

Comment: using https://pandoc.org/MANUAL.html#option--top-level-division ?

Comment: OK, that makes a little more sense. Thanks!

Comment: @nxl4 I'm going down this exact path, including parts, and don't have my yaml file or scripts yet. I don't suppose you have a GitHub repo you could share?